# Would a single API call returning all the data in JSON be faster than multiple API calls returning parts?

Tags: php, android, jquery, json, api

I am currently building an android application using HTML5 and JS, and working with an API that returns data in the JSON format. This data is put together using a series of PHP scripts.

The app uses various different datasets of for example the `Classes` and `Classmates`. Would it be faster/better to make a single API call and return all of these datasets in a single JSON structure or is it a better idea to make different API calls and only when the users wants to view them?

I know the fewer remote calls, the better, but would this impact the performance of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer to your question is yes, it would impact performance negatively. Especially if you are making your requests synchronously.

In general, it makes complete sense to be able to return a collection of elements as well as a singular instance of an element with an API. This is a common practice in REST APIs. For example `apiUrl/users/` represents a list of users where `apiUrl/users/1` would represent one user with id = 1. Make sure you are pulling ONLY the data you need in the fewest number of API calls possible.

To increase efficiency, make requests asynchronously.

UPDATE:
   I realize you might be looking to mix two different data types together (`Classes` and `Classmates`) so for future reference i'll add this bit of information about API design. Make your `apiUrl/Classes/1` url return details about the `Class` as well as an array of `Classmates` objects who are current enrolled in that class. This is typically a good practice because it eliminates the need for making one API call for each individual classmate, or a seperate call to receive a list of `Classmates` for one `Class`.

If you really want to increase flexibility, add some parameters to tell the API you want the `Classmates` list included with your request. A very basic implementation could look something like this: `apiUrl/Classes/1?classMates=y`

Answer (score 1):

Pull the data on a demand basis. If the user is on a screen to see all classmates for a certain class, it would be slow and unnecessary to pull extra data that they won't even be using.

Save what data you can from previous API calls from screen to screen as well.